# Uploading file to document library using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

Below code is working for uploading file to document library. Now in document library there are folders

Document Library

- folder1 -- subFolder1
- folder2 -- subfolder2

where in code can I assign folders so that the document gets uploaded to the specific folder.

```
function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName) {  
    //Get Client Context,Web and List object.  
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();  
    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();  
    var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('DocumentList');  

    //Convert the file contents into base64 data  
 var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);  
    var i, length, out = '';  
    for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1) {  
        out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);  
    }  
    var base64 = btoa(out);  
    //Create FileCreationInformation object using the read file data  
    var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
    createInfo.set_content(base64);  
    createInfo.set_url(fileName);  


    //Add the file to the library  
       var uploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo)  
    //Load client context and execcute the batch  
    clientContext.load(uploadedDocument);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace the below line:

```
createInfo.set_url(fileName);
```

with this

```
createInfo.set_url("https://sitecollectionurl/DocumentList/folder1/subFolder1/" + fileName);
```

Since you might not want to hardcode, you can pass the folder name as parameter and use it inside as below:

```
function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, folderPath , fileName) {  
    ...
    //Create FileCreationInformation object using the read file data  
    var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
    createInfo.set_content(base64);  
    createInfo.set_url("https://sitecollectionurl/DocumentList/" + folderPath + "/" + fileName);  


    //Add the file to the library  
       var uploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo)  
    //Load client context and execcute the batch  
    clientContext.load(uploadedDocument);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);  
}
```

Usage:

```
uploadFile(arrayBuffer,"folder1/subFolder1",fileName);
```

You must ensure that the necessary folders are present.